# code check system using ace code editor and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

I am in the middle of a project where we want to use ace code editor embedded in the browser. I would like to implement it just like how codeschool or any other teaching platform do using ace library. I want users to solve a given prompt in the code editor and want to grab it and run some test in the background before giving the result back to the result window. I am new to this field and would like to get some advice from someone who has the similar experience. Can anyone let me know where I can start and like a brief summary of flow I should follow? e.g

1. user solve the prompt
2. user hit "Run or Submit" button
3. the code will be delivered to a server that handles the result or it will be handled on the client side.
4. give the user the result of the prompt.

Comment: That depends how much you care about the user's solutions. For example, if you were building this for a site that evaluates people for interviews/work, you'd do the solution checking server side. If it's just a teaching platform, then it should be fine just testing the code on the client, and maybe sending it to server if you want to keep a record of their submissions.

Comment: thank Prashanth. great. I think then I can do the check on the client side. But I am not sure how I can interpret the string value from ace editor to run a test on the client side. do you have any advice on it?

Comment: The simple and most common way is to `eval()` the code, then run tests against it, using a test library like Chai/Mocha etc. For example, I found this blog post by Khan Academy, where they mention using Ace editor, by `eval`ing the code. http://ejohn.org/blog/introducing-khan-cs/

Comment: great. Thank you. I will have a look and try.